# I don't see the data submitted after I refresh the page one or two times : how does the ArrayList get empty on its own?

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have to submit some links via the control panel of a website and they should automatically appear in the jsp page,next time the user refreshes it.To do this,I click the submit button after pasting the link,a post request is generated and servlet handles that link by calling a bean's function from itself and stores the link there in the ArrayList.

*snippet from servlet*

```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   String link = request.getParameter("song link");
   StoreSongLink store = new StoreSongLink(); // A Bean class
   int ret = store.storeSongLink(link); // calls the bean method
   // if ret is 0,return to the cpanel home page
```

*Bean class*

```
public class StoreSongLink {
public static ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();

 public int storeSongLink(String link) {
    linkList.add(link);
    return 0;
 }   
}
```

After this I try to fetch the submitted links as *(in the jsp page)* :

```
        <%! ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>(); %>

       <%
           songList = StoreSongLink.linkList;
       %> 

       <% for (String links : songList){ %>
             <li><%= links%></li>
       <%}%>
```

I see the link submitted one or two time and then it gets vanished after I refresh the same page and I see the message that isn't any link submitted yet! Why is this so ? I know this may not be the best of approach but still I want to do this way.

Why don't i see the link submitted after I refresh the page ? How is the data lost from the ArrayList ?

Answer (score 0):

The StoreSongLink object that you create in the servlet has its scope limited to that particular invocation. Where are you storing this object, or its contents? You need to put it either in the session or in a database, depending on the functionality that you expect.

Comment: can you please explain this _"The StoreSongLink object that you create in the servlet has its scope limited to that particular invocation. "_

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to instantiate that SongStoreLink once per session. Before creating the object you should retrieve it from the session, if one is found use it otherwise create the object ans save it in the session.

Comment: I want to embed songs in the jsp page.For this I submit the link of those songs from the control panel of my website.The link that I submit is put inside a `ArrayList` which is there in the bean and called by the servlet.Then I load the jsp page which tries to get all the links submitted in the ArrayList.But it shows the link submitted only once and after i refresh the page it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

Get the StoreSongLink instance from a session or something similar.

```
StoreSongLink store = (StoreSongLink)request.getSession().getAttribute("storeSongLink");
if (store == null)
{
   store = new StoreSongLink();
   request.getSession().setAttribute("storeSongLink", store);
}
```

Alternatively you could use a singleton pattern to create/get the StoreSongLink instance.
Furthermore it would be wise refactoring the storeSongLink method and avoid scriptlets in JSP. There are plenty of frameworks which seperate code and layout.